# The reduce graph obtained by the regularity lemma

Tags: co.combinatorics

Applying the regularity lemma to a graph $G$, we can get an $\epsilon$-regular partition of $V(G)$, say $V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_m$. For some $d>0$, the reduce graph $R$ is defined as the graph with vertex-set $[m]$ and edge-set $\{ij\colon\, \mbox{$(V_i, V_j)$ is $\epsilon$-regular in $G$ and has density at least $d$}\}$. My question is: for certain elementary graph parameters $p(G)$ (such as the independence number), what is the relationship between $p(G)$ and $p(R)$? Or let $R'$ be the subgraph obtained from $R$ by deleting some small portion of vertices (if necessary), is there any relationship between $p(G)$ and $p(R')$?